# Tab highlighting based on buttons in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have 3 tabs in my application, as below:

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#one')}"><a data-toggle="tab" class="tab-txt-color" href="#one" ng-click="selectTab('fruits')">Fruits</a></li>
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#two')}"><a data-toggle="tab" class="tab-txt-color" href="#two" ng-click="selectTab('veggies')">Veggies</a></li>
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#three')}"><a data-toggle="tab" class="tab-txt-color" href="#three" ng-click="selectTab('decors')">Decors</a></li>
```

.js

```
 $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
    return viewLocation === $location.path();
  };
    

For above code, when any of the tab is clicked it gets highlighted.
```

But I have previous and next buttons added to the content of above tabs. How do I make the respective tab active when clicked on previous button.

```
  <div>
 .......
 ......
 ....(content of Veggies tab)
 [End of this tab there are 2 buttons]

 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="margin-top:20px;" align="right">
 <a href="#"><img src="core/static/images/previous-btn.gif"  border="0" ng-click="selectTab('fruits')"></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="core/static/images/next-btn.gif"  border="0" ng-click="selectTab('decors')"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer if you need the next and previous actions should work on sequence.
Add an array of tabs with its names and a variable to store the current tab name

```
$scope.tabs = ["fruits","veggies","decors"];
$scope.currentTab = "";
```

Add 2 more methods for Previous and Next button click

```
$scope.nextTab = function(){
    if($scope.currentTab == ""){
        $scope.selectTab(tabs[0]);
    }
    else {
        var index = $scope.tabs.indexOf($scope.currentTab);
        var nextIndex = ((index + 1) < $scope.tabs.length) ? (index+1) : 0;
        $scope.selectTab($scope.tabs[nextIndex]);
    }
}
$scope.prevTab = function() {
    if($scope.currentTab == ""){
        $scope.selectTab(tabs[0]);
    }
    else {
        var index = $scope.tabs.indexOf($scope.currentTab);
        var prevIndex = ((index == 0) ? ($scope.tabs.length - 1) : (index-1);
        $scope.selectTab($scope.tabs[prevIndex]);
    }
}
```

Add one more line in selectTab method to store current tab name

```
$scope.selectTab = function(tab){
    //other functionalities

    //add this line
    $scope.currentTab = tab;
}
```

Update click methods in Next and Previous buttons

```
<a href="#"><img src="core/static/images/previous-btn.gif"  border="0" ng-click="prevTab()"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="core/static/images/next-btn.gif"  border="0" ng-click="nextTab()"></a>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Tried with above code. It didn't work